# nsurlconnection returns no error when

Tags: ios, objective-c

Does

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
```

return error = nil when data is not nil?

if there is data returned, is error always nil?

that's what the documentation says ...

how is error affected by the http status code?
like if the status code is not 200, does it always return an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NSError is not related with the HTTP Response. The NSError is returned when the connection itself failed. A bad HTTP status code means the request itself works for the client.

You have to manually check the status code.

```
NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
int responseStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
```

Now you can test if the status is 200.

To answer to your questions :

> return error = nil when data is not nil?
>
> if there is data returned, is error always nil?

If the data == nil then you should have error != nil

> how is error affected by the http status code? like if the status code
>   is not 200, does it always return an error?

If you got a status code then it means the connection worked (from a connection request point of view, not the HTTP one) so error == nil and data should be not nil

Answer (score 0):

You answered your first two questions yourself already. The documentation is right there.

Regarding the status code: No, status codes do not affect the `NSError` at all. This `NSError` is reserved for when a `NSURLConnection` actually fails in a non-HTTP way. For example when you're actually offline and no request can be made at all. Also keep in mind, that `NSURLConnection` is not tied to HTTP requests in any way. iOS also supports FTP connections out of the box (no status code like in HTTP here) and you can even write your own protocol support for almost anything you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there will just occure an `NSError` if the request failed to get the data. But if the server returns you any other status code than 200, it will be like an error because you couldn't get the data. But by checking the status code you can give more specific error messages to the user instead of just `Couldn't load data`, because you can specify if there was an `NSError` which could be caused by missing internet connection or if you received any bad status code and the server is not available..